# Media query not working for specific div class

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I've searched thoroughly on the internet but to no avail. Currently I have the below text for `left-author` and `right-author` class

```css
#wrapper-author {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.left-author {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}
.right-author {
  width: 50%;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
}
```

and this for the media queries. Every single query but `left-author` and `right-author` will work.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .left-author .right-author {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: initial;
  }
  .widget_highlighted_posts .single-article {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Here's the HTML....

```html
<div id="wrapper-author">

   <div class="left-author clearfix">

<h4>I guess you want to know who <?php the_author(); ?> is.</h4>

<span style="font-family: sofia-pro; font-size: 20px;"><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></span><?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();

$published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
?>

   </div>
   <div class="right-author clearfix">
<?php userphoto_the_author_photo() ?>

<div class="social-links">
<ul>
<li  style="font-family: aw-conqueror-carved-one;">Follow <?php the_author_meta( first_name ); ?> on</li>
  <?php $facebook = get_the_author_meta('facebook'); if ($facebook) { ?><li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('facebook'); ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
  <?php $twitter = get_the_author_meta('twitter'); if ($twitter) { ?><li><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php the_author_meta('twitter'); ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
  <?php $googleplus = get_the_author_meta('googleplus'); if ($googleplus) { ?><li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('googleplus'); ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php $instagram = get_the_author_meta('instagram'); if ($instagram) { ?><li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('instagram'); ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php $pinterest = get_the_author_meta('pinterest'); if ($pinterest) { ?><li><a href="<?php the_author_meta('pinterest'); ?>"  target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
        <?php $email = get_the_author_email(); if ($email) { ?><a href="mailto:<?php the_author_email(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li><?php } ?>
        <li><a href="http://maphappy.org/author/<?php the_author_meta( 'user_login' ); ?>/feed/"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
  </ul></div>

 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any HTML to go with that CSS?

Comment: I just added it in — sorry for the vote down, I am new to Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1):

your missing a comma `,` to separate 2 classes in same declaration

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .left-author, .right-author {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: initial;
  }
  .widget_highlighted_posts .single-article {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**(OP has given the HTML code)

you are missing a `li` open tag just before `a href:mailto` (from what I saw not the issue here)

So, here is a snippet with your HTML included (excluding PHP tags):

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    /*demo , applies box-model */
}
#wrapper-author {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.left-author {
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    border:1px dashed green   /* demo styles */
}
.right-author {
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: right;
    border:1px dashed red   /* demo styles */
}
@media screen and (max-width: 380px) {
    .left-author, .right-author {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: initial;
    }
    .widget_highlighted_posts .single-article {
        float: none;
        margin-right: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-author">
  <div class="left-author clearfix">

    <h4>I guess you want to know who is.</h4>

    <span style="font-family: sofia-pro; font-size: 20px;"></span> 
  </div>
  <div class="right-author clearfix">
    <div class="social-links">
      <ul>
        <li style="font-family: aw-conqueror-carved-one;">Follow
          <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>

          </li>
         <!--the opening LI tag was missing here below -->
          <li><a href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="http://maphappy.org/author/feed/"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a>

          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dippas, I made the change but that doesn't work. Every other class seems to be working fine without the comma as well.

Comment: you need to show us some relevant HTML then, but that was a mistake for sure